# modification to allow quick sort to an array containing duplicate elements

Tags: java, quicksort

My code below works well for an array with distinct numbers, but fails for an array containing duplicates. How can I modify the code below to work even for an array containing duplicates?

```
import java.util.Random;

public class QuickSortNew {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
//      int[] a = {1,4,10,3,8,7,5,2,6,9};
//      int[] a = {1,49,30,15,27,21,1,20,1,39};
//      int[] a = {33, 47, 4, 9, 27, 16, 3, 10, 4, 43};
//      int[] a = {3, 1, 4, 1, 10, 9, 74, 16, 99, 27, 31, 43, 28, 33, 47};
        int[] a = {3, 4, 4};

//      int[] a = new int[10];
//      populate(a);
//      print(a);
//      System.out.println("");
        fun(a, 0, a.length-1);
        print(a);
    }

    static void fun(int[] a, int l, int h)
    {
        if(l >= h)
            return;

        int pivot = a[(l+h)/2];
        int startl = l;
        int starth = h;
        while(l < h)
        {
            while(a[l] < pivot)
                l++;
            while(a[h] > pivot)
                h--;

            if(l < h)
            {
                int t = a[l];
                a[l] = a[h];
                a[h] = t;
            }
        }
        fun(a, startl, l-1);
        fun(a, l+1, starth);
    }

    static void populate(int[] a)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        for(int i = 0;i<10;i++)
            a[i] = rand.nextInt(50);
    }

    static void print(int[] a)
    {
        for(int i = 0 ;i<a.length;i++)
            System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

I searched around a bit and found the code below. However, I do not want to do this as doing *if (i <= j)* { doesn't make sense right away, since if i==j, that should be the pivot, and you would just want to fix that position instead of again continuing the process. Instead, please suggest a different change to my code above.

```
private void quickSort(int lowerIndex, int higherIndex) {

        int i = lowerIndex;
        int j = higherIndex;
        // calculate pivot number, I am taking pivot as middle index number
        int pivot = array[lowerIndex+(higherIndex-lowerIndex)/2];
        // Divide into two arrays
        while (i <= j) {
            /**
             * In each iteration, we will identify a number from left side which
             * is greater then the pivot value, and also we will identify a number
             * from right side which is less then the pivot value. Once the search
             * is done, then we exchange both numbers.
             */
            while (array[i] < pivot) {
                i++;
            }
            while (array[j] > pivot) {
                j--;
            }
            if (i <= j) {
                System.out.println("i=="+i+",j=="+j+",entering inside the condition...");
                exchangeNumbers(i, j);
                //move index to next position on both sides
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }
        // call quickSort() method recursively
        if (lowerIndex < j)
            quickSort(lowerIndex, j);
        if (i < higherIndex)
            quickSort(i, higherIndex);
    }

    private void exchangeNumbers(int i, int j) {
        int temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
```

EDIT : Was able to solve it. This implementation below, to me, makes a lot more sense than the implementation which is widely found online. According to me, if the front and back pointers are same, the traversal should stop since we have an array where the first half is less than, and second half is higher than the pivot. I don't like the implementation above, since they continue even though i==j.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class QuickSortNew {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
//      int[] a = {1,4,10,3,8,7,5,2,6,9};
//      int[] a = {1,49,30,15,27,21,1,20,1,39};
//      int[] a = {33, 47, 4, 9, 27, 16, 3, 10, 4, 43};
//      int[] a = {3, 1, 4, 1, 10, 9, 74, 16, 99, 27, 31, 43, 28, 33, 47};
//      int[] a = {3, 4, 4};
//      int[] a = {1,2,7,6,10,11,4,12,13,5,14,15,8,3,9};
//      int[] a = {1,7,6,10,11,4,12,13};
//      int[] a = {3, 1, 4, 1, 10, 9, 74, 16, 99};

        Random rand = new Random();
        int n = rand.nextInt(50)+1;
        int[] a = new int[n];
        int[] b = new int[n];
        populate(n,a);
        for(int i = 0;i<a.length;i++)
            b[i] = a[i];
        System.out.print("Original array : ");
        print(b);
        System.out.println("");
        fun(a, 0, a.length-1);
        System.out.print("My sort     : ");
        print(a);
        Arrays.sort(b);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("Library sort: ");
        print(b);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Is my sort equal to library sort ? "+Arrays.equals(a, b));
    }

    static void fun(int[] a, int l, int h)
    {
        if(l >= h)
            return;

        int pivot = a[(l+h)/2];
        int pivotpos = (l+h)/2;
        int startl = l;
        int starth = h;
        while(l < h)
        {
            while(a[l] <= pivot && pivotpos!=l )
                l++;
            while(a[h] >= pivot && pivotpos!=h )
                h--;

            if(l < h)
            {
                int t = a[l];
                a[l] = a[h];
                a[h] = t;

                if(l==pivotpos)
                    pivotpos = h;
                else if(h == pivotpos)
                    pivotpos = l;
            }
        }
        fun(a, startl, l-1);
        fun(a, l+1, starth);
    }

    static void populate(int n, int[] a)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        for(int i = 0;i<n;i++)
            a[i] = rand.nextInt(50);
    }

    static void print(int[] a)
    {
        for(int i = 0 ;i<a.length;i++)
            System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: What about `while (array[i] <= pivot)`